# How to handle tab hiding on load and loading content on demand via server call using angular material?

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-material, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

API's used : Angularjs, Angular material for tabs and ui-grid(ui-grid.info)

I have five tabs, currently i am loading all the five tabs using angular material with content as grid from angular-ui-grid; data loaded from backend using external pagination per page data from backend.

HTML Code:

```
<div cg-busy="{promise:downloadCSVPromise,message:'Downloading...'}">
    <div cg-busy="{promise:loadingData,message:'Loading Data...'}">
        <section style="min-height: 434px;" class="wrap">

            <div ng-cloak>
                <md-content>
                    <md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex" md-border-bottom md-autoselect md-dynamic-height>
                        <md-tab id="tab1" ng-disabled="disableParts">
                            <md-tab-label>Tab 1</md-tab-label>
                            <md-tab-body>
                                <div class="custom-csv-link-location"></div>
                                <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-auto-resize class="myGrid">
                                    <div class="grid-msg-overlay" ng-hide="!vm.loading">
                                        <div class="msg">
                                            <span>
                                    Loading Data...
                                    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
                                    </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="watermark" ng-show="!gridOptions.data.length">No data available</div>
                                </div>
                            </md-tab-body>
                        </md-tab>
                        <md-tab id="tab2" ng-disabled="disableService">
                            <md-tab-label>Service Order</md-tab-label>
                            <md-tab-body>

                                <div ui-grid="serviceOrderGridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection ui-grid-exporter class="myGrid">

                                    <div class="watermark" ng-show="!serviceOrderGridOptions.data.length">No data available</div>
                                </div>
                            </md-tab-body>
                        </md-tab>
                        <md-tab id="tab3" ng-disabled="disableSales">
                            <md-tab-label>Sales Order</md-tab-label>
                            <md-tab-body>
                                <div ui-grid="salesGridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection ui-grid-exporter class="myGrid">

                                    <div class="watermark" ng-show="!salesGridOptions.data.length">No data available</div>
                                </div>
                            </md-tab-body>
                        </md-tab>
                        <md-tab id="tab4" ng-disabled="disableNC">
                            <md-tab-label>Non Conformances</md-tab-label>
                            <md-tab-body>
                                <div ui-grid="nonconfGridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection ui-grid-exporter class="myGrid">

                                    <div class="watermark" ng-show="!nonconfGridOptions.data.length">No data available</div>
                                </div>
                            </md-tab-body>
                        </md-tab>
                        <md-tab id="tab5" ng-disabled="disableBOM" md-on-select="resize()">
                            <md-tab-label>System BOM</md-tab-label>
                            <md-tab-body>
                                <div id="bom-charts">
                                    <div class="chartBx bom-pie-chart">

                                        <nvd3 options="pie_options" data="pie_data"></nvd3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="chartBx bom-stack-chart">
                                        <nvd3 options="stack_options" data="stack_data"></nvd3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div ui-grid="bomGridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection ui-grid-exporter class="myGrid">

                                    <div class="watermark" ng-show="!bomGridOptions.data.length">No data available</div>
                                </div>
                            </md-tab-body>
                        </md-tab>

                    </md-tabs>
                </md-content>
            </div>

        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script Code:

```
function partsData(type) {

            $scope.serversideFilters = [];
            $scope.type=type ? type : "";

            var paginationOptions = {
                pageNumber: 1,
                pageSize: 25,
                sort: null
            };


            var originatorEv;
            $scope.openMenu = function ($mdOpenMenu, ev) {
                originatorEv = ev;
                $mdOpenMenu(ev);
            };



            $scope.switchTabs = function (row, type) {
                console.log('Menu item clicked - ' + row.entity.materialnum);

                if(type === "service_order"){
                    $scope.selectedIndex = 1;
                    $scope.drillKeyword = row.entity.materialnum;
                    serviceOrderData('drill');

                } else if(type === "sales_order"){
                     $scope.selectedIndex = 2;
                     $scope.drillKeyword = row.entity.materialnum;
                     salesData('drill');

                } else if(type === "NC"){
                     $scope.selectedIndex = 3;
                     $scope.drillKeyword = row.entity.materialnum;
                     nonconfData('drill');

                } else if(type === "BOM"){
                     $scope.selectedIndex = 4;
                     $scope.drillKeyword = row.entity.materialnum;
                     bomData('drill');

                } 

            };


            var fileNm = 'Parts_' + today + '.csv';

            $scope.gridOptions = {
                enableSelectAll: false,
                enableRowSelection: false,
                enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
                exporterCsvFilename: fileNm,
                exporterMenuPdf: false,
                enableFiltering: true,
                showGridFooter: true,
                paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
                paginationPageSize: 25,
                useExternalPagination: true,
                enableGridMenu: true,
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        name: 'materialnum', displayName: 'Part Number', cellClass: '', headerCellClass:'header-server-filtered',enableFiltering: false,width: 150,
                        cellTemplate: "<div class='ui-grid-cell-contents'><md-menu  md-offset='0 45' md-position-mode='target target'><md-button class='md-icon-button' ng-click='grid.appScope.openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)'><i class='fa fa-indent'></i></md-button><md-menu-content width='2'><md-menu-item><md-button ng-click='grid.appScope.switchTabs(row,&apos;service_order&apos;)'>Service Order </md-button></md-menu-item><md-menu-item><md-button ng-click='grid.appScope.switchTabs(row,&apos;sales_order&apos;)'>Sales Order</md-button></md-menu-item><md-menu-item><md-button ng-click='grid.appScope.switchTabs(row,&apos;NC&apos;)'>Non Conformances</md-button></md-menu-item><md-menu-item><md-button ng-click='grid.appScope.switchTabs(row,&apos;BOM&apos;)'>System BOM</md-button></md-menu-item></md-menu-content></md-menu><span title='{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}' ng-click='grid.appScope.showAdvanced($event, row, col)' class='partNum'>{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</span></div>"
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'materialdesc', displayName: 'Part Description', headerCellClass: 'header-server-filtered', width: 200,
                        filter: {
                                condition: $scope.filterPartDesc
                            },
                        cellTemplate: '<div ng-if="row.entity.materialdesc" title="{{row.entity.materialdesc}}" >{{row.entity.materialdesc}}</div><div ng-if="!row.entity.materialdesc"></div>',
                    },
                    sparableColumn,
                    consumableColumn,
                    cvvColumn,
                    npiColumn,
                    criticalColumn,
                    trColumn,
                    ipColumn,
                    faiColumn,
                    altpartsColumn,
                    repariableColumn,
                    {
                        name: 'onhandstock', displayName: 'On Hand Stock', headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader, enableFiltering: false,
                        cellTemplate: '<div ng-if="row.entity.onhandstock" class="tcenter">{{row.entity.onhandstock}}</div><div ng-if="!row.entity.onhandstock"></div>'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'totalstock', displayName: 'Total Stock Limit', headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader, enableFiltering: false,
                        cellTemplate: '<div ng-if="row.entity.totalstock" class="tcenter">{{row.entity.totalstock}}</div><div ng-if="!row.entity.totalstock"></div>'
                    }
                ],

                onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

                    /* Facet filter for server side filtering*/
                    $scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged( $scope, function() {
                         var grid = this.grid;
                         $scope.serversideFilters = [];
                        angular.forEach(grid.columns, function(value, key) {
                            if(value.filters[0].term) {
                                var dummy = {};
                                console.log('FILTER TERM FOR ' + value.colDef.name + ' = ' + value.filters[0].term);
                                dummy['k'] = value.colDef.name;
                                dummy['v'] = value.filters[0].term;
                                $scope.serversideFilters.push(dummy);
                            }
                        });
                        getPage();
                    });

                    $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, function (grid, sortColumns) {
                        if (sortColumns.length === 0) {
                            paginationOptions.sort = null;
                        } else {
                            paginationOptions.sort = sortColumns[0].sort.direction;
                        }
                        getPage();
                    });
                    $scope.gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize) {


                        paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
                        paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
                        getPage();
                    });
                }
            }
            $scope.filterPartDesc = function(searchTerm, callValue){
                console.log('Inside Filter Part Description' +searchTerm );

                if(value.filters[0].term) {
                    var dummy = {};
                    console.log('FILTER TERM FOR ' + value.colDef.name + ' = ' + value.filters[0].term);
                    dummy['k'] = value.colDef.name;
                    dummy['v'] = value.filters[0].term;
                    $scope.serversideFilters.push(dummy);
                }

            };

            var getPage = function () {

                var url = "http://test.server.com:8080/Dash/TestServlet";
                var keyword = $scope.keyword ? $scope.keyword : '';
                var paramsObj = {};

                if($scope.type == "drill"){
                    keyword = $scope.drillKeyword;
                    paramsObj['ftype'] = 'exact';
                }

                paramsObj['query'] = keyword;
                paramsObj['start'] = paginationOptions.pageSize * paginationOptions.pageNumber - paginationOptions.pageSize;
                paramsObj['rows'] = paginationOptions.pageSize;



                if (type && type !== '') {
                    if (type === 'cvv')
                        paramsObj[type] = 'YES';
                    if (type === 'sparable')
                        paramsObj[type] = 'YES';
                    if (type === 'consumable')
                        paramsObj[type] = 'C';
                }


                angular.forEach($scope.serversideFilters, function(obj){

                    paramsObj[obj.k] = obj.v;
                });


                $scope.loadingData = $http.get(url, { params: paramsObj, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
                    .then(function (res) {

                        $scope.gridOptions.totalItems = res.data.numFound;
                        $scope.gridApi.grid.options.totalItems = res.data.numFound;
                        $scope.numFound = res.data.numFound;
                        var firstRow = (paginationOptions.pageNumber - 1) * paginationOptions.pageSize;

                        $scope.filters = res.data.facetFieldsMap;
                        var dummy = {
                            label: "",
                            value: ""
                        }

                        $scope.consumableFilter = [];
                        $scope.sparableFilter = [];
                        $scope.cvvFilter = [];
                        $scope.npiFilter = [];
                        $scope.criticalFilter = [];
                        $scope.trFilter = [];
                        $scope.ipFilter = [];
                        $scope.faiFilter = [];
                        $scope.altpartsFilter = [];
                        $scope.repariableFilter = [];

                        angular.forEach($scope.filters, function (ukey, uvalue) {

                            if (uvalue === "sparable") {
                                angular.forEach(ukey, function (key, value) {
                                    dummy = {};
                                    dummy.label = value;
                                    dummy.value = value;
                                    $scope.sparableFilter.push(dummy);
                                });
                            }
                            if (uvalue === "consumable") {

                                angular.forEach(ukey, function (key, value) {
                                    /*if (value === 'N'){
                                        value = 'NO';
                                    } 
                                    if (value === 'Y'){
                                        value = 'YES';
                                    } */
                                    dummy = {};
                                    dummy.label = value;
                                    dummy.value = value;
                                    $scope.consumableFilter.push(dummy);
                                });
                            }
                            if (uvalue === "cvv") {
                                angular.forEach(ukey, function (key, value) {
                                    dummy = {};
                                    dummy.label = value;
                                    dummy.value = value;
                                    $scope.cvvFilter.push(dummy);
                                });
                            }
                            if (uvalue === "npi") {
                                angular.forEach(ukey, function (key, value) {
                                    dummy = {};
                                    dummy.label = value;
                                    dummy.value = value;
                                    $scope.npiFilter.push(dummy);
                                });
                            }
                            if (uvalue === "crtclpart") {
                                angular.forEach(ukey, function (key, value) {
                                    dummy = {};
                                    /*if (value === 'N'){
                                        value = 'NO';
                                    } 
                                    if (value === 'Y'){
                                        value = 'YES';
                                    } */
                                    dummy.label = value;
                                    dummy.value = value;
                                    $scope.criticalFilter.push(dummy);
                                });
                            }
                            if (uvalue === "traderstrctd") {
                                angular.forEach(ukey, function (key, value) {
                                    dummy = {};
                                    dummy.label = value;
                                    dummy.value = value;
                                    $scope.trFilter.push(dummy);
                                });
                            }
                            if (uvalue === "ipsnstv") {
                                angular.forEach(ukey, function (key, value) {
                                    dummy = {};
                                    dummy.label = value;
                                    dummy.value = value;
                                    $scope.ipFilter.push(dummy);
                                });
                            }
                            if (uvalue === "fai") {
                                angular.forEach(ukey, function (key, value) {
                                    dummy = {};
                                    dummy.label = value;
                                    dummy.value = value;
                                    $scope.faiFilter.push(dummy);
                                });
                            }
                            if (uvalue === "alternatepart") {
                                angular.forEach(ukey, function (key, value) {
                                    dummy = {};
                                    dummy.label = value;
                                    dummy.value = value;
                                    $scope.altpartsFilter.push(dummy);
                                });
                            }
                            if (uvalue === "reprblcd") {
                                angular.forEach(ukey, function (key, value) {
                                    dummy = {};
                                    dummy.label = value;
                                    dummy.value = value;
                                    $scope.repariableFilter.push(dummy);
                                });
                            }
                        });

                        sparableColumn.filter.selectOptions = $scope.sparableFilter;
                        consumableColumn.filter.selectOptions = $scope.consumableFilter;
                        cvvColumn.filter.selectOptions = $scope.cvvFilter;
                        npiColumn.filter.selectOptions = $scope.npiFilter;
                        criticalColumn.filter.selectOptions = $scope.criticalFilter;
                        trColumn.filter.selectOptions = $scope.trFilter;
                        ipColumn.filter.selectOptions = $scope.ipFilter;
                        faiColumn.filter.selectOptions = $scope.faiFilter;
                        altpartsColumn.filter.selectOptions = $scope.altpartsFilter;
                        repariableColumn.filter.selectOptions = $scope.repariableFilter;

                        $scope.gridOptions.data = res.data.partSearchList;
                        if ($scope.gridOptions.data.length === 0) {
                            $scope.gridOptions.enablePaginationControls = false;
                        }


                    });
            };

            $scope.toggleFilterRow = function () {
                $scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering = !$scope.gridOptions.enableFiltering;
                $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
            };

            getPage();
        }
```

Currently i am loading all the tabs with all the hits going to backend to fetch data but as per the requirement i need to change like below:

Only one tab will be loaded as per user selects in a dropdown to load the data and then inside the loaded tab we have links to other tab which will dynamically load the remaining tab/s on demand

I tried to hide or disable the material tabs but was getting error on load of the page on below lines :

$scope.gridApi.grid.options.totalItems = res.data.numFound;

I kept the loading of particular tab conditionally but then the HTML had the gridOptions defined and script was not initialized with the gridOptions it also threw error.

Finally i had tried below as well but didnt worked out.

```
$scope.serviceOrderGridOptions = {};

        $scope.gridOptions = [];
        $scope.serviceOrderGridOptions.data = [];
```

How can we make a tab load on demand with no issues on load of the page and also how to load the ui-grid inside it.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Create a sample plunker with where you are at so the community can be more helpful. This doesn't tell us much. For instance, based on your standard $scope.gridApi, I am assuming you are using ui-grid, but you don't call that out anywhere.

Comment: Couldn't create a plunker but have updated the whole question with code snippets and all the grid level data as well. Please have a look and call out if any details required.

Comment: So I am seeing grid options for `gridOptions`
`serviceOrderGridOptions`
`salesGridOptions`
`nonconfGridOptions`
`bomGridOptions`, but you have only `gridOptions` defined in your controller, so 4/5 of the grids appear to be config-less

Comment: I gave just an example for html and showed all of the grid options hope that's fine :)